# Azure CDN to Azure Application Gateway (internal) connectivity issue

Tags: azure-application-gateway, azure-cdn

I have deployed webapps in AKS with internal LB and application gateway created with backend as internal LB.

I am able to access the application using app gateway URL : **app-gateway-url/webapp/**.

I have configured azure CDN also with custom origin as **app-gateway-url/webapp/**, when we try to access the application using CDN url, it is showing following error

“Request cannot be served”

Note: Application gateway is only accessible from our intranet(internal certificate).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal only Application Gateways are not accessible via the public internet, only via the Virtual Network that they are in.

Azure CDN can only have Azure Storage Accounts, Web Apps, Cloud Services, or other internet addresses that are publicly available over the internet.

If you want to have this content behind a CDN, you will need to make your Application Gateway publicly accessible.